# How can I tight jeans without stitching it?

Tags: clothing, comfort

As some of my jeans are loosed and I have to tight all these so I Can wear these again. Is there any other way to tight jeans except stitching?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wet the jeans in hot water and put them on wet. go outside and allow them to dry in the sun in the course of an afternoon. When dry, remove them, rewet with hot water, and repeat. This is how "cowgirls" get skin-tight jeans in the US.

Comment: This only works when the jeans are a bit wide, not if you have lost a lot of weight or the jeans were way to wide to start with.

Answer (score -1):

Wash jeans in hot water and dry it in sun light. Repeat this step when your jeans become perfect to waer. Button or zip them up so they fall as they would when you'd wear them. Stand in front of a mirror. Note the areas where you would like the jeans to fit more snugly. Then place button or zip them that place. Find a place that can be cover under your belt.
Boil jeans in water 5 to 10 mint.

Comment: Wash in hot water only temporarily shrinks cotton jeans. And it may even stretch if it is made with synthetics.

Comment: It's for cotton jeans. When you have a jeans made with synthetics then put method two on it.

Comment: Its depends on jeans

Comment: Cotton does not shrink unless it has been stretched before, not due to hot water. And the amount it shrinks after having been stretched is limited and it will stretch that much again in wearing. So washing in hot water is useless. Wool will shrink when washed in hot water but then it is still the movement and not the temperature.

Comment: Yes you are right. Different types of jeans have different method for shrinks

Comment: Can you explain why down vote

Comment: Very easily, your answer is useless, as jeans do not really shrink when gotten wet, cold not hot.

Comment: Kindly see this

Comment: https://www.google.com.pk/amp/s/m.wikihow.com/Make-Your-Jeans-Tighter%3famp=1

Comment: I have a Reference and I search more about this topic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86187/discussion-between-willeke-and-chawlish-boy).